# PHP contact form not sending email even after saying email sent

Tags: php, html, contact-form

I've put together a simple PHP contact form on my website. 
When I submit the message its says message sent. 
But I don't receive the email.

The code I'm using is below

```
<?php
    $action=$_REQUEST['action'];

    if ($action=="") /* display the contact form */
    {
?>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit">
    <div class="field half first">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input name="name" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name">
    </div>
    <div class="field half">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input name="email" id="email" type="email" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="message">Message</label>
        <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="6" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    </div>
    <ul class="actions">
        <li><input value="Send email" class="button alt" type="submit"></li>
    </ul>
</form>

<?php
    } 
    else /* send the submitted data */
    {
        $name=$_REQUEST['name'];
        $email=$_REQUEST['email'];
        $message=$_REQUEST['message'];

        if (($name=="")||($email=="")||($message==""))
        {
            echo "All fields are required, please fill <a href=\"\">the form</a> again.";
        }
        else{       
            $from="From: $name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email";
            $subject="Message sent using your contact form";
            mail("xyz@website.com", $subject, $message, $from);
            echo "Email sent!";
        }
    }  
?>
```

The MX records are set for google apps, would that have anything to do with why the email is not being sent?

Comment: your just echoing the "Email sent" after mail function dose't mean email sent . so do something like this and check it if(mail("xyz@website.com", $subject, $message, $from)) { echo "Email sent!";  }else { echo "email not sent "; }

Comment: Its already hosted on godaddy, I tried what you asked, it still says email sent, but havent received anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine to me.

If you are doing this on localhost, it may be that the address you send your mail to rejects it because SMTP is not properly configured.

Try uploading this to a remote server if that is the case. Or configure SMTP on your computer.

Comment: Maybe it doesnt support mail? Try php_info() or phpinfo() i don't relever the exact name of the function, and look for mail

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, it is a godaddy issue, the MX Entry >> Mail routing needs to be set to

Remote.

[image]